# phone call and sending emails from UWP app

Tags: c#, email, win-universal-app, phone-call

i want to make a phone call and send an email from my UWP but i don't know  how to ... is their anyway to help me get through this by providing for me an example or some tutorial..

This is the code i tried but it didn't work

```
 using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

    PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();

    phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = "2065550123";
    phoneCallTask.DisplayName = "Gage";

    phoneCallTask.Show();
```

thanks in advance and i really appreciate your help .
**Update**
I just found  this code snippet

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI("+380442308888", "The Name goes here");
```

and it looks like i need to add a  reference `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.`
but i can't find it in the reference list .. am i on the right way and if so please help add this reference

Comment: Check this might be helpfull, How to [Send Email and SMS](https://youtu.be/W-2pOqNsNNc) in Windows 10 #UWP app #CSharp

Answer (score 2):

you must use PhoneCallManager to make calls

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.calls.phonecallmanager

if you want to send an email you need to create a EmailMessage object and use ShowComposeEmailAsync

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/sending-email

Update:

here is the example for using calls.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PhoneCall

Comment: Thank youu ...what i actually need is to choose an user (that i already have his number stored in my Mysql database) once i click on the call button .. so  can you please give me some help to solve tis problem  .. i really appreciate it